# How did the Third Sister move so quickly?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In *Obi-Wan Kenobi* Part V, the Third Sister is stabbed in the gut and left to die, while Kenobi and his rebel cell are trying to escape from the planet.

In *Obi-Wan Kenobi* Part VI,

> The Third Sister is on Tatooine, looking for the young Luke Skywalker, while Kenobi and his rebel cell are still trying to escape from the Star Destroyer.

So, how did the Third Sister move so quickly? Is there plot armor involved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hyperdrive for the rebel's ship was damaged and so they couldn't make the jump to escape (*The Last Jedi* anyone?). They were trying to fix it but until they could it meant that they were stuck with snail pace.

> **Roken:** Hyperdrive's almost ready. Move all power to the rear shields. We'll head for Tessen. Get you out from there.
>
> **Obi-Wan:** We're not gonna make it to Tessen, are we?
>
> **Roken:** Motivator's shot. Power couplings are bad. I'm workin' on it, but those shields won't last forever.
>
> <sub>*Obi-Wan Kenobi*, Season 1 Episode 6, "Part VI"</sub>

Conversely Reva just had to jump into her ship and could use her hyperdrive to go straight to Tatooine with no stops in between.

Comment: "The Last Jedi anyone?" -- Or *Empire*, or *Phantom*

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- They wouldn't!

Comment: The real question is: why did they just leave a ship for Reva sitting around when they departed? Whoever keeps track on that Imperial ship has gotta be annoyed that he's short one for no damn reason.